# In org-mode how to break current section and escape to upper level

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode, normal hierarchy goes like :

```
* Section 1
  Content of section 1

  ** Section 1-1
     Content of section 1-1

  ** Section 1-2
     Content of section 1-2
```

As I understand it, everything after a header belongs to that section until it meets another (higher or lower) header.

But is it possible to break the current section without using another header, and to continue the content of the previous section? Something like :

```
* Section 1
  Content of section 1

  ** Section 1-1
     Content of section 1-1
  ** Section 1-1 end

  Content of section 1 continues ...

  ** Section 1-2
     Content of section 1-2
  ** Section 1-2 ends


  Content of section 1 continues ...
```

Comment: How is this meant to look in the output?  Sections in documents usually don't work in that way.

Comment: I've just added an answer to [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997099/in-org-mode-how-to-break-current-section-and-escape-to-upper-level) on stackoverflow.

Comment: You shouldn't be posting the same question on both sites at the same time. It results in question redundancy and makes it more difficult for any user searching in future to reach to the healthier set of question and answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "off-topic" (for lack of a better flag) because you asked the same question at the same time on
[Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997099/in-org-mode-how-to-break-current-section-and-escape-to-upper-level).

Comment: For what it's worth, the question is actually on-topic for this site, but as a general practice one should not post the same question on two different SE sites at the same time, in part for the reasons @kuashalmodi raised.  If people would prefer this question remain here, feel free to vote to reopen, and then vote to close the version that's on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Dan Also, I remember seeing a similar question a while back, but could not find it. Can you try searching for it? In that too, the conclusion was that that could not be done. **Update** Found it!

Comment: Duplicate of: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/12177/115

Comment: @kuashalmodi: nice find.  I've replaced the rationale for the close to "duplicate."

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Apparently I underestimated the activeness of this site. I thought I might get more answers by posting it again on StackOverflow.